# Firestore is not returning all the documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query for all the users stored in firestore collection using the below code(I know that querying for entire users is not good, but lets assume i have a compelling use case).

```
let app = admin.initializeApp(<firebase config>)
const db = app.firestore()

let querySnapshot = await db.collection('users').
                       get()
querySnapshot.forEach((user) => {
  <script logic>
})
```

I have two problems
1) The query is returning different number of docs for every execution
2) The query is not returning all the docs

Can anyone help me in identifying the problem(above code is run as part of script in nodejs environment).

Comment: Aren't you missing `'` at the end of `users`.

Comment: sorry my bad...corrected it ...copy paste error.

Comment: Does your query return the right results when using a ‘where’ clause?

Comment: @dhanrajm cna you please attach a screen shots or response of your query? Have you checked in fireStore the number of users?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I cannot use where clause since all my fields are string

Comment: @AbdulhaqShah cannot do that since that will expose the user data

Comment: @dhanrajm i got it but have you go through the standard limitation of [FireStore Limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). May be you are exceeding this that's why.

Comment: How many user document exist in the database?

Comment: @AlexMamo 347 users

Comment: @AbdulhaqShah : I never got any alerts on the limits and i am on paid plan

Comment: And your query returns how many?

Comment: @dhanrajm there is also limitation on paid plan. Also i have read an article about firebase limitation which don't allow queries something like that.i.e. To get all records of the specific route. There is no code issue, that's limitation from firestore.

Comment: @AlexMamo it switches between 17 and 9. After Abduihaq mentioned about limits, I suspect there could be per second limits on reading

Comment: @AbdulhaqShah Can you paste the link to that article?

Comment: @dhanrajm [here it is](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/heres-what-i-wish-i-knew-before-i-started-using-firebase-9110d393e193/)

Comment: If you hit any of Firestore's throughput or quota limits, the operation will fail instead of silently performing a partial operation. In addition: there is no throughput limit on reads.